# Modify operands to cout

Tags: c++, gcc

I want to access `cout` operands for example

```
cout << "Hello";
```

here  I want to access the string "Hello" which is a operand of operator `<<` and want to modify.

Can I do this? If so how?

Comment: You want to do _what_? (Have a look at `std::stringstream`, that's probably what your looking for, but your question is currently _very_ hard to understand)

Comment: You can't modify string literals such as `"Hello"`.

Comment: @Raghu: We've put this question on hold because you're not telling us enough. Most importantly, what result do you want? What should happen to `std::cout << 2+2` (clearly you cannot modify the rules of math, 2+2 will always be 4). If you provide all those extra details, we can take it off hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `cout << "Hello"`, you cannot access `"Hello"` anymore. You have to access it beforehand.

You cannot modify the string literal `"Hello"` at runtime, because it is of type `const char*`. You have to create a string and modify the string:

```
std::string hello = "Hello";
hello[0] = 'B';
std::cout << hello; // prints "Bello"
```